# peer channel fectch error: MSP SampleOrg is not defined on channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, msi-patch

I've deployed Hyperledger Fabric and cd into fabric-samples/test-network, I can run the command `./network.sh up createChannel`, the containers' status are "up" and I can delploy a chaincode.
However, when I intend to run the command

```
peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o $ORDERER_CONTAINER -c $CH_NAME --tls --cafile $TLS_ROOT_CA
```

to fetch the channel config, I got

```
2022-05-17 10:09:31.644 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2022-05-17 10:09:31.647 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Expect block, but got status: &{FORBIDDEN}
Error: can't read the block: &{FORBIDDEN}
```

I've checked the orderer's log, and it gives

```
2022-05-16 11:39:04.803 UTC [policies] SignatureSetToValidIdentities -> WARN 061 invalid identity: certificate subject=CN=peer0.org1.example.com,OU=COP,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US serialnumber=268337738708423250738667250199689187829 error="MSP SampleOrg is not defined on channel"
2022-05-16 11:39:04.803 UTC [policies] SignatureSetToValidIdentities -> WARN 062 invalid identity: certificate subject=CN=peer0.org1.example.com,OU=COP,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US serialnumber=268337738708423250738667250199689187829 error="MSP SampleOrg is not defined on channel"
2022-05-16 11:39:04.803 UTC [policies] SignatureSetToValidIdentities -> WARN 063 invalid identity: certificate subject=CN=peer0.org1.example.com,OU=COP,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US serialnumber=268337738708423250738667250199689187829 error="MSP SampleOrg is not defined on channel"
2022-05-16 11:39:04.803 UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 064 [channel: mychannel] Client 12.11.52.5:50846 is not authorized: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Readers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
```

I noticed that in the `network.sh up createChannel` logs, the command run correctly with results like

```
Fetching the most recent configuration block for the channel
+ peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o orderer.example.com:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -c mychannel --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
2022-05-16 15:35:42.810 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2022-05-16 15:35:42.816 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Received block: 1
2022-05-16 15:35:42.816 UTC [channelCmd] fetch -> INFO 003 Retrieving last config block: 1
2022-05-16 15:35:42.818 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 004 Received block: 1
Decoding config block to JSON and isolating config to Org2MSPconfig.json
+ configtxlator proto_decode --input config_block.pb --type common.Block
+ jq '.data.data[0].payload.data.config'
```

I've tried copy the same commands in the logs, and run it in the `cli bash`
The results is still the same.

I can't find similar errors and I don't understand why I got this.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The error `error="MSP SampleOrg is not defined on channel"` is a bit strange given that the Hyperledger samples nearly always use Org1MSP, Org2MSP, etc. Have you changed an MSP value to something else in the sample YAML files?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by modify the `docker-compose-test-net.yaml`, I split the `cli` into `cli1,cli2`,one for each organization, and the `peer channel fetch` command runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently. Turns out the org names we were using were inconsistent - `org1` when registering peers vs. `Org1` when performing a later connection